# VirtualBox the windows of virtual machines list disappears

Tags: virtualbox

How can I show the windows of the virtual machine list again?

Like this:
[The windows disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFPj8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and was able to restore the list by deleting the configuration file under `$HOME\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` (Windows host)

On Linux and MacOS, the path should be something like

`$HOME/.config/VirtualBox` (Linux host)

`$HOME/Library/VirtualBox` (MacOS host)

I'm sure this is not the most elegant solution but it seems to restore the default settings wihtout hassle

Hope I could help, Cheers
JR

Edit: Annoyingly (albeit naturally) this also resets all kinds of pop-ups and warning that you might have to accept again...